# How to evaluate logarithms in Maxima?

Tags: logarithm, maxima

Following examples from [here](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_10.html#SEC52), and [here](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_8.html) I tried this:

```
log2(x) := log(x) / log(2);
log2(8), float;
```

But this doesn't give 3, instead I get `log(8)/log(2)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to simplify radicals:

```
(%i1) log2(x) := log(x) / log(2);
                                          log(x)
(%o1)                          log2(x) := ------
                                          log(2)
(%i2) radcan(log2(8));
(%o2) 

                             3
```

Answer (score 1):

or use float :

```
float(log(8)/log(2));
```

gives:

```
2.999999999999999
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to calculate logarithms in base 10:

You can also write in the command line: **load(log10)**;(enter)

Then for the calculation of the decimal logarithm: log10(100);(Enter) the result is 2, and so on.  To exemplify I did some calculations with log10. These results are shown in the picture below

[image]