# How to simplify log(8)/log(2) in Maxima CAS?

Tags: integer, logarithm, maxima

I want to simplify log(8)/log(2)

I know that

```
log(8)/log(2) = log(2^3)/log(2) = 3*log(2)/log(2) = 3
```

it is possible [in Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_10.html#IDX333) but not works for me:

```
Maxima 5.41.0 http://maxima.sourceforge.net
using Lisp GNU Common Lisp (GCL) GCL 2.6.12
Distributed under the GNU Public License. See the file COPYING.
Dedicated to the memory of William Schelter.
The function bug_report() provides bug reporting information.
(%i1) log(8)/log(2);
                                    log(8)
(%o1)                               ------
                                    log(2)
(%i2) logexpand;
(%o2)                                true
(%i3) log(2^3)/log(2);
(%o3)                               log(8)
                                    ------
                                    log(2)

(%i4) logexpand;
(%o4)                                true
```

I  use:

```
round(float(log(8)/log(2));
```

but I think that it is not the best solution ( I work with integers)

**Questions:**

1. How to do it ?
2. Why it works [in Maxima doc](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_10.html#IDX333), but not in my Maxima ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271504/how-to-evaluate-logarithms-in-maxima

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to evaluate logarithms in Maxima?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271504/how-to-evaluate-logarithms-in-maxima)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me in Maxima 5.43.0:

```
(%i1) radcan(log(8)/log(2));
(%o1)                                  3
(%i2) radcan(log(2^3)/log(2));
(%o2)                                  3
```

Maxima says that

```
 -- Function: radcan (<expr>)

     Simplifies <expr>, which can contain logs, exponentials, and
     radicals, by converting it into a form which is canonical over a
     large class of expressions and a given ordering of variables; that
     is, all functionally equivalent forms are mapped into a unique
     form.  For a somewhat larger class of expressions, 'radcan'
     produces a regular form.  Two equivalent expressions in this class
     do not necessarily have the same appearance, but their difference
     can be simplified by 'radcan' to zero.
```

In this context it factorizes the number `8` and then moves the power 3 outside of the logarithm, enabling cancellation of the remaining log of 2:

```
(%i3) radcan(log(8));
(%o3)                              3 log(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

log(8.0)/log(2.0); 3

To exemplify I did the calculation in the command line. This result is shown in the picture below

[image]